# vs 2008 Source Control compare options

Tags: tfs

Since I have moved to a new machine I have installed vs 2008 with team explorer again, I can't see "Compare" options which I was able to see previously.

When right clicking a source file opened, we have "Source Control", inside that I can only see the "Annotate" option but Compare option is missing. I can see the compare option when in solution explorer and right click that file, but when a file is opened and then try to compare with server version, can't see the compare option then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Tools -> Options -> Source Control
```

Under "Visual Studio Team Foundation Server" select "Configure User Tools" which will allow you to configure a comparison tool.